# Jackson for beginners in Eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jackson

let me just say that I'm still learning Java and the subtleties of Eclipse, and I come to you because I am unsure how to properly phrase my question to Google or to StackOverflow's search engine. Apologies if its infinitely trivial.

I am trying to understand the process of converting JSON-format strings into objects in Java. I found following example online:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;public class JsonToJavaConverter {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JsonToJavaConverter.class);

public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException {

    JsonToJavaConverter converter = new JsonToJavaConverter();

    String json = "{\n" + "    \"name\": \"Garima\",\n"
            + "    \"surname\": \"Joshi\",\n"
            + "    \"phone\": 9832734651}";

    // converting JSON String to Java object
    converter.fromJson(json);
}

public Object fromJson(String json) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException {
    User garima = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, User.class);
    logger.info("Java Object created from JSON String ");
    logger.info("JSON String : " + json);
    logger.info("Java Object : " + garima);

    return garima;
}

public static class User {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private long phone;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", phone="
                + phone + "]";
    }
}}
```

Now, here's the silly part (please don't string me up for asking):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

Are all underlined in red with Eclipses only hint, being that "The import org.apache.log4j cannot be resolved".

As a newcomer to both Eclipse and Java, this leaves me absolutely dumbstruck.

Could anyone please tell me what needs doing to resolve this basic issue?

Deeply appreciated.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn basic JSON before you learn Jackson.  JSON is blazingly simple, Jackson makes it complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the libraries (jar files) to the project's build path in Eclipse.

You can find these libraries in Maven Central here:

[Log4j](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Clog4j%7Clog4j%7C1.2.17%7Cbundle)

[Jackson](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml.jackson.core%7Cjackson-core%7C2.3.1%7Cbundle)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the relevant Jar files to your projects classpath

http://javahowto.blogspot.co.uk/2006/06/set-classpath-in-eclipse-and-netbeans.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the log4j jar to your classpath.  Assuming that you're not using maven or gradle, you can download it from [Apache's site](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html).  Then put it in some suitable shared location and add it to your project's classpath.  I think it's about the 3rd or 4th item in the Project Properties dialog, iirc.